# Preventing caching of gettext

Tags: php, caching, localization, gettext, po

How can I disable gettext caching in development phase, so I can modify mo file without restarting apache?

(in http://php.net/manual/es/book.gettext.php a portion of a class is proposed for this task, but in do not work, in particular it use an undefined constant `GETTEXT_CACHING`, also I hear that Zend_Translate dose not have this issue, what technique is used by it? )

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Translate` implements their own mo file reader, so it's just like parsing a file.

That's the only solution I know to avoid caching.